# Background and top bar configurations does not apply at startup

Tags: linux, x11, x-dwm

I am on Manjaro Linux and using dwm. I have made some changes (additions) in my `~/.xinitrc` file to have my wallpaper set and display date & time on top bar when I log in. But I cannot have these changes applied or having an issue with my files such as `~/.xinitrc` and `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.

I already have compton, feh (also nitrogen but do not prefer) and xsetroot installed on my system. I also applied [this](https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/autostart/) patch to my dwm in order to have an autostart.sh file.

Here is my `~/.dwm/autostart.sh` file:

```
#! /bin/bash
compton --config ~/.config/compton/compton.conf &
feh --bg-fill /home/root113/Pictures/0239.jpg &
xcompmgr &

while true; do
     xsetroot -name "$(date)"
     sleep 1s
done &
```

This did not work. There exist a similar problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1528954/sxhkd-chaining-chords-doesnt-work-in-autostart-sh-of-dwm) asked 29 days ago but yet not answered or recieved any comments.

Then I search the net for more answers and help and realised that I should try to edit my `~/.xinitrc` file. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager 
from here)

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

DEFAULT_SESSION=gnome-session

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

get_session(){
    local dbus_args=(--sh-syntax --exit-with-session)
    case $1 in
        awesome) dbus_args+=(awesome) ;;
        bspwm) dbus_args+=(bspwm-session) ;;
        budgie) dbus_args+=(budgie-desktop) ;;
        cinnamon) dbus_args+=(cinnamon-session) ;;
        deepin) dbus_args+=(startdde) ;;
        enlightenment) dbus_args+=(enlightenment_start) ;;
        fluxbox) dbus_args+=(startfluxbox) ;;
        gnome) dbus_args+=(gnome-session) ;;
        i3|i3wm) dbus_args+=(i3 --shmlog-size 0) ;;
        jwm) dbus_args+=(jwm) ;;
        kde) dbus_args+=(startkde) ;;
        lxde) dbus_args+=(startlxde) ;;
        lxqt) dbus_args+=(lxqt-session) ;;
        mate) dbus_args+=(mate-session) ;;
        xfce) dbus_args+=(xfce4-session) ;;
        openbox) dbus_args+=(openbox-session) ;;
        *) dbus_args+=($DEFAULT_SESSION) ;;
    esac

    echo "dbus-launch ${dbus_args[*]}"
}

exec $(get_session)

#Personal customizations below

compton --config ~/.config/compton/compton.conf &
feh -bg-fill /home/root113/Pictures/0239.jpg &
xcompmgr &

while true; do
    xsetroot -name "$(date)"
    sleep 1s
done &

exec dwm
```

Still, the problem haven't got solved.
Then I changed the line

```
feh -bg-fill /home/root113/Pictures/0239.jpg &
```

with this:

```
~/.fehbg &
```

What is written inside `~/.fehbg` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
feh --no-fehbg --bg-fill /home/root113/Pictures/0239.jpg
```

Did not solve my problem.

Then I decided to export my `~/.xinitrc` file in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` by adding this line at the end of the file:

```
 export PATH="${PATH}:/home/root113/.xinitrc"
```

This did not work either. So I kept my solution seeking on the net and in one of the forums I was told that I should make my `~/.xinitrc` file executable. So I did that with the following command:

```
 chmod +x ~/.xinitrc
```

Did not work either. Every time I log back in or reboot, it is the same annoying black screen and top bar with no date being displayed at all that my eyes stares.

I also tried replacing `~/file` with `/home/root113/file` in every file in case of the path was not recognised. It was not a solution at all. Did not work.

I kept searching and searching for answers and read these useful answers and articles:

- [Problem with $PATH and executable file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16242/problem-with-path-and-executable-file)
- [Adding a directory to your PATH](https://astrobiomike.github.io/bash/modifying_your_path)
- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)
- [How to set your $PATH variable in Linux](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux)

None of them refers to a kind of problem/issue that I have **directly**, but indirectly. So I decided to (probably a stupid idea but worth giving a try since I started to ran out of solutions) add the following to my `~/.profile` file:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/home/root113/.xinitrc"
```

Did not work either then I added the following to my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Did not work again.

I searched high and low for a solution on the net. I am literally in a desperate situation at the moment. I have no hope left but asking here. Thank you for reading through here. I know it has been a long question but I wanted to explain the problem to you in details and also wanted to tell you what solutions I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that in `~/.xinitrc` file I have to declare my personel settings before all other stuff. Just placed them on top of the file as:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager 
from here)

#Personal customizations below

compton --config ~/.config/compton/compton.conf &
feh -bg-fill /home/root113/Pictures/0239.jpg &
xcompmgr &

while true; do
    xsetroot -name "$(date)"
    sleep 1s
done &

exec dwm

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

DEFAULT_SESSION=gnome-session

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

get_session(){
    local dbus_args=(--sh-syntax --exit-with-session)
    case $1 in
        awesome) dbus_args+=(awesome) ;;
        bspwm) dbus_args+=(bspwm-session) ;;
        budgie) dbus_args+=(budgie-desktop) ;;
        cinnamon) dbus_args+=(cinnamon-session) ;;
        deepin) dbus_args+=(startdde) ;;
        enlightenment) dbus_args+=(enlightenment_start) ;;
        fluxbox) dbus_args+=(startfluxbox) ;;
        gnome) dbus_args+=(gnome-session) ;;
        i3|i3wm) dbus_args+=(i3 --shmlog-size 0) ;;
        jwm) dbus_args+=(jwm) ;;
        kde) dbus_args+=(startkde) ;;
        lxde) dbus_args+=(startlxde) ;;
        lxqt) dbus_args+=(lxqt-session) ;;
        mate) dbus_args+=(mate-session) ;;
        xfce) dbus_args+=(xfce4-session) ;;
        openbox) dbus_args+=(openbox-session) ;;
        *) dbus_args+=($DEFAULT_SESSION) ;;
    esac

    echo "dbus-launch ${dbus_args[*]}"
}

exec $(get_session)
```

Everything is working properly now.